# Defining type to create objects out of type's picked keys seems to be broken

Tags: typescript

Why doesn't this work?

```js
class Demo<T, ArrayOfKeysOfT extends (keyof T)[]> {
    constructor(args: {[index in keyof ArrayOfKeysOfT]: T[ArrayOfKeysOfT[index]]}) {
        args;
    }
}
```

The error I am getting says

> Type `ArrayOfKeysOfT[index]` cannot be used to index type `T`.

However it seems like this code should be fine. I'm unsure if this is by design or a bug within Typescript.

**UPDATE**

I realized the issue here is that `ArrayOfKeysOfT[index]` where `index` is the type `keyof ArrayOfKeysOfT` results not only in a type that encompasses all the members of `ArrayOfKeysOfT`, but also contains all the different keys of an array in general (length, push, pop, etc.), which is why it cannot be used to key into type T.

What I am trying to accomplish is the following.

Say I define some interface

```
interface Example {
    one: string;
    two: boolean;
}
```

Then this should be allowed

```
new Demo<Example, ['one', 'two']>({
    one: "some string",
    two: false
});
```

This should cause a compiler error because 'two' is not in the the type parameter array

```
new Demo<Example, ['one']>({
    one: "some string",
    two: false
});
```

This should cause a compiler error because three is not a key of the first type parameter argument

```
new Demo<Example, ['one', 'two', 'three']>({
    one: 'some string',
    two: true,
    three: 4
});
```

And lastly this should not work because the value assigned to the member 'two' in the args object is of the wrong type

```
new Demo<Example, ['one', 'two']>({
    one: "some string",
    two: "another string"
});
```

Comment: I can only get this to compile if I change it to `T[ArrayOfKeysOfT[number]]` but that doesn't take `index` into account. So please, what exactly are you trying to achieve? How's `args` supposed to look like, in your mind?

Shouldn't `index` be of type `number` since `ArrayOfKeysOfT` is an `Array`? I can't quite get the usage of `keyof ArrayOfKeysOfT`, since `keyof any[]` would return `number | "length" | "toString" | "toLocaleString" | "pop" | "push" | "concat" | "join" | "reverse" | "shift" | "slice" | "sort" | "splice" | "unshift" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | ... 13 more ... | "values"`.

Comment: Good point. Updated to include some further context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Demo<T, ArrayOfKeysOfT extends (keyof T)[]> {
    constructor(args: {[P in ArrayOfKeysOfT[number]]: T[P]}) {
        console.log(args);
    }
}

interface ABC {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
}

const demo1 = new Demo<ABC, ['a', 'b']>({ 'a': 0, 'b': 'hi' }); // works!
const demo2 = new Demo<ABC, ['a', 'd']>({ 'a': 0, 'd': null }); // ERROR - Type '["a", "d"]' does not satisfy the constraint '("a" | "b" | "c")[]'
const demo3 = new Demo<ABC, ['c']>({ 'c': 'not a boolean' }); // ERROR - Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
const demo4 = new Demo<ABC, ['b', 'c']>({ 'a': 0 }); // ERROR - argument of type '{ 'a': number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ b: string; c: boolean; }'.
```

I'm glad to help!

**UPDATE**:

Just wanted to remind you (or let you know) that the built-in `Pick<T, K>` utility type exists in the standard TypeScript library, which makes the `Demo` type sorta redundant:

```
let a: Pick<ABC, 'a' | 'b'> = {'a': 2, 'b': 'hello'};
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much! I'm going to try and think of a better name for this question. Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: @AjaxLeung I'd say "Defining type to create objects out of type's picked keys seems to be broken". Also, please see my edit.

Comment: Makes sense. The reason why I'm not using the Pick is because I'm going to do some more complex things with the type after indexing into T.